# ADB/fastboot stopped working in recovery mode

Tags: adb, usb, recovery-mode, nexus-4, twrp

Something went wrong when I updated my Nexus 4 (Mako) with Paranoid Android 6 via TWRP 2.8.

I formated the phone in Recovery Mode but now I unable to connect to adb to transfer new OS image in the internal memory. So, I'm stuck with a phone without operating system.

The battery loads well when connected to my debian but I can't see anything related to the phone with `lsusb`.

I'm definetly not an expert with TWRP, but I noticed an error when I try to start `adb sideload` : `E:Unable to mount /usb-otg`.

I'm also considering to open the device but from informations I found there is no way to extract the internal memory to flash it from my debian.

How can I debug that ? Alternatively, what are my options to send a new image to my phone ?

*UPDATE 1*: When I enter in fastboot mode (the screen with the android picture) I see:

> FASTBOOT MODE
>   VARIANT - mako 8GB
>   HW VERSION - rev 11
>   BOOTLOADER VERSION - MAKOZ10o
>   BASEBAND VERSION - M9615A-CEFWMAZM-2.0.1700.48
>   CARRIER INFO - None
>   SIGNING - production
>   SECURE BOOT - enabled
>   LOCK STATE - unlocked

In this mode I still have nothing on `lsusb` or `fastboot devices -l`.

*UPDATE 2*: Here is what I see in `dmesg -w | grep usb` when I connect the phone :

> [3416.043914] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
>   [3416.155984] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
>   [3416.371985] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
>   [3416.587946] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 23 using hci_hcd
>   [3416.700008] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
>   [3416.915999] usb 3-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
>   [3417.131964] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
>   [3417.132235] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
>   [3417.336256] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
>   [3417.539975] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 24, error -71
>   [3417.651994] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
>   [3417.652222] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
>   [3417.856035] usb 3-2: Device not responding to setup address.
>   [3418.060047] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 25, error -71
>   [3418.060149] usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

Comment: How's fastboot working?

Comment: `fastboot devices -l` gives me nothing.

Comment: Are you in fastboot mode? Don't restrict yourself inside TWRP.

Comment: I updated my comment with information relative to fastboot mode. I'm definetly new with android, but don't you think I should see something in `lsusb` whatever mode I use ?

Comment: I updated my question with details from dmesg. Apparently something is wrong on this side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the communication problem on the USB bus came from a "loose" connection of in the micro USB. I succeeded to reset a factory image just leaving the phone and the connector in a particular position to keep the contact.